# Extract string between nth occurrence of character and another character

Tags: r, regex

```
filelist <- c(
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171015_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171016_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171017_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171018_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171019_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171020_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171021_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt",
  "http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171022_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt"
)
```

I am looking to extract the string between the 5th occurrence of `/` and `_`

Ex: From                                     `"http://content.caiso.com/green/renewrpt/20171015_DailyRenewablesWatch.txt"`
I would want `20171015`.
I have tried

```
regmatches(filelist, regexpr("/{4}([^_]+)", filelist))
```

but it returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few approaches which use regular expressions:

```
sub(".*(\\d{8}).*", "\\1", filelist)

sub(".*/", "", sub("_.*", "", filelist))

sub("_.*", "", basename(filelist))

sapply(strsplit(filelist, "[/_]"), "[", 6)

gsub("\\D", "", filelist)

m <- gregexpr("\\d{8}", filelist)
unlist(regmatches(filelist, m))

strcapture("(\\d{8})", filelist, data.frame(character()))[[1]]

library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(filelist, "\\d{8}", simplify = TRUE)
```

These solutions do not use regular expressions at all:

```
substring(filelist, 41, 48)

substring(basename(filelist), 1, 8)

read.table(text = filelist, comment.char = "_", sep = "/")[[6]]

as.Date(basename(filelist), "%Y%m%d")  # returns Date class object
```

**Update:** Added a few more approaches.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
gsub("(?:.*/){4}([^_]+)_.*", "\\1", filelist)
# [1] "20171015" "20171016" "20171017" "20171018" "20171019" "20171020" "20171021"
# [8] "20171022"
```

We need to also match the stuff in front of each of the slashed in the capture.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(x = filelist,
       start = sapply(gregexpr(pattern = "/", filelist), function(x) x[5])+1,
       stop = sapply(gregexpr(pattern = "_", filelist), function(x) x[1])-1)
#[1] "20171015" "20171016" "20171017" "20171018" "20171019" "20171020" "20171021"
#[8] "20171022"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to get rid of the url first:

```
filelist <- basename(filelist)
```

Then try removing all after "_" using `str_remove` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(filelist, "_.*")
```

Output:

> [1] "20171015" "20171016" "20171017" "20171018" "20171019" "20171020" "20171021" "20171022"

Check the `lubridate` package's `ymd` function in case you would like to turn this into a date.