# stringr remove n-th occurence of a character

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I know this question has been asked and answered before (e.g. [Replace Nth occurrence of a character in a string with something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874998/replace-nth-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-with-something-else) or [Extract string between nth occurrence of character and another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979202/extract-string-between-nth-occurrence-of-character-and-another-character)), but for whatever reason I can't get the respective regex solutions work.

I basically want to remove the n-th occurence of a certain phrase from a character string, in particular, in the example I want to remove the second occurence of "ab", but neither of my attempts work.

I have a workaround by using `str_locate_all`, and then do a `str_sub` based on the positions of the phrase, but I'm hoping for a straightforward regex solution with `str_remove` or `str_replace` if I want to replace this second occurrence with something.

```
text <- "abcdabef"
```

expected output:

```
"abcdef"
```

Non-working solutions that I tried (among many others):

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(y, "(?:ab){2}")
str_remove_all(y, "(?:ab){1}.*(ab)")
```

Comment: You could do `sub('(^.*)(ab.*)ab(.*$)', '\\1\\2\\3', text)`

Comment: The second occurrence? `sub("(ab.*?)ab", "\\1", "abcdabef")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the second occurrence only, you need to use

```r
sub("(ab.*?)ab", "\\1", "abcdabef")
```

To remove the nth occurrence, use a limiting quantifier after the group where the only `min` value should be equal to `n-1`:

```r
n <- 2
sub(paste0("((?:ab.*?){",n-1,"})ab"), "\\1", "abcdabef", perl=TRUE)
```

**Note**:

You need to use `sub` and not `gsub` since you only need a single replacement to be done.

*Pattern details* (when `n=3`):

- `((?:ab.*?){2})` - Group 1 (`\1`): two occurrences of `ab` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars (since I am using `perl=TRUE` here, if you need multiple line matching support, add `(?s)` at the start or replace `.*?` with `(?s:.*?)`) as few as possible
- `ab`  - an `ab`

If you have arbitrary strings with special chars in them, you need to escape them:

```r
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}

word <- "a+(b)"
word <- regex.escape(word)
text <- "a+(b)1___a+(b)2___a+(b)3___a+(b)4"
n <- 3 # Let's remove the 3rd occurrence of a+(b)
sub(paste0("((?:", word, ".*?){",n-1,"})", word), "\\1", text, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "a+(b)1___a+(b)2___3___a+(b)4"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nq7KvP/1).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using `stringr` and no `regex` (it also works for any `n`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <-  "abcdabef"

n <- 2

str_locate_all(text, "ab") %>% .[[1]] %>% 
  when(n <= nrow(.) ~ `str_sub<-`(text, .[n, 1], .[n, 2], value = ""), ~ text)

#> [1] "abcdef"
```

Comment: Yes, that was my initial approach, but a it tedious, so I was looking for a straightforward solution.

Comment: I have just updated my solution to a less tedious one, @deschen.