# replace first occurence of character with X and second occurence of character with Y

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm stuck with renaming a column in my data frame. I want to replace the first occurence of `_` with an `r` and the second occurence of `_` with a `c`.

```
dat <- data.frame(Q12_1_1 = NA)
```

While I can do two sequential `str_replace` (because it just replaces the first occurence), I'm wondering how a combined regex pattern could look like.

Works:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat |>
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with('Q12'),
              .fn = ~str_replace(., '_', 'r')) |>
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with('Q12'),
              .fn = ~str_replace(., '_', 'c'))
```

The question about n-th occurence of a pattern has been asked before ([stringr remove n-th occurence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316863/stringr-remove-n-th-occurence-of-a-character)), but I'm not sure how I can specifically do different replacements for the same pattern.

Expected output:

```
data.frame(Q12r1c1 = NA)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Q12_1_1 = NA)

library(tidyverse)

dat |>
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with('Q12'), .fn = ~ str_replace(., '_(\\d+)_(\\d+)', 'r\\1c\\2'))
#>   Q12r1c1
#> 1      NA
```

Or

```r
dat |>
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with('Q12'), .fn = ~ str_replace(., '_(.*?)_', 'r\\1c'))
#>   Q12r1c1
#> 1      NA
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit on what exactly this is doing? My guess is that it searches for underscores and then with the `(\\d+)` stuff, it creates groups (according to the stringr cheat sheet). And then in the replacement we address each group with `\\number`?

Comment: Yeah. Right. Using `(\\d+)`we create a capture group of digits whose value with can get via `\\1` for the first group and so on.